# Whoosh seems not take into account the maximum difference in position between each word

Tags: parsing, whoosh

I am working with the library WHOOSH in order to make query on my documents but my understanding is limited.

As the documentation expose I have the  folowing dodument "whoosh is a very beautiful library"  and my query is  'whoosh library'~2.
I expect the searcher fail because the distance in between "whoosh" and "library" is greater than 2.

Next enclosed a mimale code to exprime the problème I have.
hsdlhhd

`import tempfile
    from whoosh.fields import Schema, TEXT, ID, NUMERIC
    from whoosh.index import create_in
    from whoosh.qparser import QueryParser
    from whoosh.query import *
index = tempfile.mkdtemp()
schema = Schema(text=TEXT(stored=True))
ix = create_in(index, schema)
writer = ix.writer()
writer.add_document(text="whoosh is a very beautiful library")
writer.commit(optimize=True)
parser = QueryParser("text", schema=ix.schema)
query = parser.parse("'whoosh library'~2")
with ix.searcher() as searcher:
    results = searcher.search(query)
    for hit in results:
        print(hit)`